# Getting only the current authenticated user's data from an easy table/view in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

Using Microsoft Azure, I've created a database using easy tables (node.js backend). I have several tables and one view.

There's a trick to making the view work like an easy table which I've done.

Problem:
When using this code to read data from the view, I receive ALL data -- including data for other users.

```
 table.read(function (context) {
 return context.execute();
 });
```

That makes sense, as I'm not specifying that I only want the authenticated user's data.

When using this code, I get NO data:

```
    // READ operation
  table.read(function (context) {
  context.query.where({ userId: context.user.id });
  return context.execute();
});
```

Using the above code for an actual table and not a view works perfectly.

From the log files:

```
    2017-01-02T18:52:00.945Z - silly: Executing SQL statement SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [dbo].[ClassData] WHERE (([userId] = @p1) AND ([deleted] = @p2));  with parameters [{"name":"p1","pos":1,"value":"sid:REMOVED"},{"name":"p2","pos":2,"value":false}]

2017-01-02T18:52:00.945Z - silly: Read query returned 2 results

sprintf() will be removed in the next major release, use the sprintf-js package instead.
2017-01-02T18:52:01.867Z - silly: Executing SQL statement SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [dbo].[StacksNamesView] WHERE (([userId] = @p1) AND ([deleted] = @p2)) ORDER BY [createdAt];  with parameters [{"name":"p1","pos":1,"value":"sid:REMOVED"},{"name":"p2","pos":2,"value":false}]

2017-01-02T18:52:01.883Z - debug: SQL statement failed - Invalid column name 'userId'.: SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [dbo].[StacksNamesView] WHERE (([userId] = @p1) AND ([deleted] = @p2)) ORDER BY [createdAt];  with parameters [{"name":"p1","pos":1,"value":"sid:REMOVED"},{"name":"p2","pos":2,"value":false}]
```

**UPDATE**:

When creating Azure App Service EasyTables, the column "userId" is automatically a part of each table. However, it's not visible when looking at the schema via the Azure Portal. This is where my confusion was.

**SOLUTION**:

When using a view as an EasyTable and you need the "hidden" userId column, just make sure you select it as part of the view! This will work as long as your other EasyTables are executing queries such as the second block of code in this post.

Comment: did you try to log : context.user.id ??

Comment: Where am I supposed to check for the log? I did try that and I tried putting in log: "HELLO" but it's not anywhere in the output file.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the view doesn't have the userId column that all of the real tables automatically have. So now the question is, how can I add this "hidden" column?

Comment: Solution found, question updated.